# When a thin lead sheet is hammered, what happens to internal energy

Tags: energy

When a thin lead sheet is hammered, what happens to internal energy, does it increase, decrease or remains the same or first increases and then decreases?

Comment: What are your thoughts or predictions?

Answer (score 2):

When you hammer a sheet of lead, you are adding *energy in form of work* into it, increasing it's internal energy. If this experiment were to be done in complete vacuum, it'd retain most of the energy, however if this experiment were to be on air, it'd lose a lot of energy in the form of sound.

Answer (score 0):

when a thin lead sheet is hammered, its internal energy is increased. this is because when we are hammering it, we are providing energy to the system which results in the increase of the energy of the system. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It gets hotter then cools down, net change 0.  A very narrow lead sheet formed into a spring would be another story because it would lose potential energy due to a change in shape.

Comment: Change in shape still is important as surface atoms have higher energy.